# What type of bacteria can I use to break down motor oil for a high school biology experiment? Any suggestions where I can find this bacteria?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I am experimenting to determine the optimum conditions for microbes to break down motor oil. The conditions I am going to test are different pH levels to resemble freshwater pH and saltwater pH. I will be using the chemical NaCl to adjust the salinity of the solution.

I have researched and found companies that provide oil-eating microbe powder. However, there is no information on what type or strain the microbe is in the power.
I'm failing to find information on what type of microbe would be best for this experiment and additionally where these types of microbes are supplied.

Comment: hit number one on google https://response.restoration.noaa.gov/about/media/who-thinks-crude-oil-delicious-these-ocean-microbes-do.html after searching for:bacteria that breaks down oil ,you can do a search for the different bacteria mentioned in the article

Comment: If you have the time, run an extra replication using dirt from a place where oil has been spilt for many years.